# Count the number of nulls in each column

Tags: sql

I've run into a DB that has tables that are excessively wide.  (600+ columns)  Even asking for the top 100 rows with no parameters takes 4 seconds.  I'd like to slim these tables down a bit.

To figure out which columns can be most easily moved to new tables, or removed entirely, I would like to know how many nulls are in each column.  This should tell me what information is likely to be least important.

How would I write a query that can find all columns and count the nulls inside those columns?

**Edit** The DB is SQL server 2008.  I'm *really* hoping not to type each of the columns individually.  It looks like sys.columns could help with this?

**Edit2** The columns are all different types.

Comment: e.g. you'd like to find the columns that are all-null so you can just drop them? painful, but `select count(*) from sometable where somecolumn is null` one-at-a-time will do the trick.

Comment: Do the columns all have the same data type?

Comment: They are not the same type.  The data is very mismatched, it ranges from drivers license numbers to address fields, to cash values, to "promises made" whatever that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @Table_Name nvarchar(max), @Columns nvarchar(max), @stmt nvarchar(max)

declare table_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
    select
        s.name,
        stuff(
            (
                select
                    ', count(case when ' + name + 
                    ' is null then 1 else null end) as count_' + name
                from sys.columns as c
                where c.object_id = s.object_id
                for xml path(''), type
            ).value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '')
    from sys.tables as s

open table_cursor
fetch table_cursor into @Table_Name, @Columns

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @stmt = 'select ''' + @Table_Name + ''' as Table_Name, ' + @Columns + ' from ' + @Table_Name

    exec sp_executesql
        @stmt = @stmt

    fetch table_cursor into @Table_Name, @Columns
end

close table_cursor
deallocate table_cursor
```

Comment: It's taking me some time to wrap my head around what you did there, but it looks good so far.  :)

Comment: Now that I understand it, that's awesome!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(case when Column1 is null then 1 end) as Column1NullCount,
    count(case when Column2 is null then 1 end) as Column2NullCount,
    count(case when Column3 is null then 1 end) as Column3NullCount,
    ...
from MyTable
```

Comment: I'm *really* hoping to avoid typing in 688 columns individually . . . perhaps sys.columns will be usable?

Comment: Why would you type them? It should be simple to get the column names (E.g., `select * from MyTable where 1=0`), depending on your database. Then it is a bit of text-editor work to get it done. Probably quicker than writing a dynamic query to do it.

Comment: I guess I'm hoping for a little more elegance since there are several tables that are well over 100 columns.  Not the end of the world if i don't have it, but it *will* take a bit more time.

Comment: take a look at my answer - you don't need to type anything :)

Comment: I don't get it - this should take 10 minutes at most with any good text editor. You could have been done 7 minutes ago :)

Comment: I suppose this is ridiculously late to matter at this point, but my problem wasn't just that there were 688 columns to that table, but there were quite a number of tables involved also.  Roman's answer accomplished what I wanted in a single run.